# LeafletJS, GeoJSON, selecting polygons

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have a GeoJSON file showing districts of Turkey. I am adding polygons as GeoJSON layer with Leaflet and I need a way of selecting polygons via id or something ( I will use jQuery ).

My purpose is changing and animating the colors of selected polygons.

I know I can loop over the GeoJSON and set different styles while looping but I need a more dynamic way.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have found a way but not sure if this is the best way...

```
var polygons = {};

addRegionalLayer();

function addRegionalLayer(){
    cityjsonLayer = L.geoJson(turkeyadm_districts, {
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
        style: function(feature) {
            return {
                fillColor: 'red',
                weight: 1,
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'white',
                dashArray: '3',
                fillOpacity: 0.7
            };
        }
    }).addTo(map);
}


function onEachFeature(feature, layer){

    // I am adding the polygon layer to the polygons dictionary with the districts name
    polygons[feature.properties.NAME_2] = layer;

}



// this is test function ---> i am setting the color of the polygon that has key name //'Kadiköy' with random colors
setInterval(function() {
    var back = ["#ff0000","blue","yellow"];
    var rand = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
    polygons['Kadiköy'].setStyle({
        fillColor:rand,
        opacity:1
    });
}, 40);
```